# How to sort bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im struggling with the order of a bar plot of mpg package, what i want is to plot the `cty` variable vs `manufacturer`, i have tried with `reorder()` and with `fct_reorder()` but i still have the same graph, this is what i have tried:

```
mpg <- ggplot2::mpg
#With fct_reorder
ggplot(mpg, aes(fct_reorder(manufacturer, cty), cty)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
#with reorder

ggplot(mpg,aes(x = reorder(manufacturer, -cty), y = cty)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I get the plot but its still unordered by the `cty` values, what i
am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're passing isn't fully aggregated the way you want. This works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mpg %>% 
    group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
    summarise(cty = sum(cty)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(manufacturer, -cty), y = cty)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

can simplify the proposed solution

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(x = reorder(manufacturer, -cty, sum), y = cty)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```